# Script for kicking specific IP addresses off your Shopify site?

Tags: ip, shopify

I am looking for a solution that will ban or kickoff a specific IP address, 76.206.12.230 and 76.93.150.192

I am using a Shopify website and do not have access or control of the server.  I can add a script to my website but that is all I really can do.

Anyone have any thoughts or suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: I found [this](http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussion/t/is-it-possible-to-block-people-from-a-certain-ip-range-or-domain-from-my-shop-37592) post. I guess you can't...

Answer (score 0):

Shopify doesn't have any 'out of the box' solution to restrict / ban visitors coming from a specific IP so far. 
You could check those IP's using JavaScript and print a blank template if they were visitng your site. 
Doing it using JavaScript can be easily spoofed.

Comment: Maybe you want to share why do you need to restrict those IP's and we can think of a turnaround.